# Android app with flash: "application descriptor file cannot be parsed"

Tags: android, flash, sdk, air

I'm new to app-programming and I'm creating an app with flash CS5.5. While the document is unsaved, I can test the app (on AIR debug launcher). When I try to test it on a mobile, it makes me save it (my version is in spanish, and 'unsaved' contains an accent), and, when I do, it's impossible to test the app, also on debug launcher. ("application descriptor file cannot be parsed"). The description file is create by flash, so it must be right, I guess. It've tried reinstalling java, and it outputs the same message. Thanks in advance.

I think the problem might be on the android SDK, which I can't link to flash on the deployment tab of my "Air settings", because the space for doing that isn't simply there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **Included files** in **General** tab of **AIR for android settings**. There are ***yourproject*-app.xml** there. It should be found in your project directory. Problem is within it.

Try to create new blank project and compare app.xml's, try publishing blank project into android device.

Make shure AIR sdk version is correct.

If nothing helps post content of ***yourproject*-app.xml** here, and ill try to help

EDIT: As i said make shure AIR sdk version is correct. If you trully have 13.0 version of sdk in your flash, then this line:

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/13.0">
```

Should be 4.0 insted of 13.0

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/4.0">
```

try it

Answer (score 2):

Try to open your FLA-file from a mapped drive instead of a network drive.

I got the same error when my file path was a network drive (\network\path), but dragging the file into an empty Flash instance from Total Commander made the file-path change to S:\myfolder\ and then the problem disapeared...

When your FLA-file is open, hold the mouse over the tap in the top to see what your file-path is.

Answer (score 0):

I've already tried that. Even if the project is blank, it gives me tha same error (once I have saved it). This is my project-app.xml file.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?> 
 <application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/13.0">
  <id>prova6</id> 
  <versionNumber>1.0.0</versionNumber> 
  <versionLabel /> 
  <filename>prova6</filename> 
  <description /> 
 <!--  To localize the description, use the following format for the description element.<description><text xml:lang="en">English App description goes here</text><text xml:lang="fr">French App description goes here</text><text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App description goes here</text></description>--> 
  <name>prova6</name> 
  <!--  To localize the name, use the following format for the name element    <name><text xml:lang="en">English App name goes here</text><text xml:lang="fr">French App name goes here</text><text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App name goes here</text></name>
  --> 
  <copyright /> 
  <initialWindow>
  <content>prova6.swf</content> 
  <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome> 
  <transparent>false</transparent> 
  <visible>true</visible> 
  <fullScreen>false</fullScreen> 
  <aspectRatio>portrait</aspectRatio> 
  <renderMode>cpu</renderMode> 
  <autoOrients>false</autoOrients> 
  </initialWindow>
  <icon /> 
  <customUpdateUI>false</customUpdateUI> 
  <allowBrowserInvocation>false</allowBrowserInvocation> 
  </application>
```